# kivy collide_point behavior not as expected

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create an application in which, three columns of labels appear side by side. Each column should be included in a BoxLayout. Scrolling the mouse wheel up and down, and depending on whether the cursor is located in the left or right BoxLayout, different events should be triggered and the labels of the left or right column should be changed accordingly.

This is the code I created:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

matrix = [500, 500, 500, 5, 5]

class LoginScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        self.container_L = MyLayout_L(orientation = 'vertical', on_touch_down = self.change_label_L)
        self.container_M = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.container_R = MyLayout_R(orientation = 'vertical', on_touch_down = self.change_label_R)

        self.label_L0 = Label(text = '3', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L1 = Label(text = '4', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L2 = Label(text = '5', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L3 = Label(text = '6', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L4 = Label(text = '7', font_size = 30)

        label_L_list = [self.label_L0, self.label_L1, self.label_L2, self.label_L3, self.label_L4]
        for item in label_L_list:
            self.container_L.add_widget(item)

        self.label_M0 = Label(text = '500', font_size = 30)
        label_M_list = [self.label_M0]
        for item in label_M_list:
            self.container_M.add_widget(item)

        self.label_R0 = Label(text = '3', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R1 = Label(text = '4', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R2 = Label(text = '5', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R3 = Label(text = '6', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R4 = Label(text = '7', font_size = 30)

        label_R_list = [self.label_R0, self.label_R1, self.label_R2, self.label_R3, self.label_R4]
        for item in label_R_list:
            self.container_R.add_widget(item)

        self.add_widget(self.container_L)
        self.add_widget(self.container_M)
        self.add_widget(self.container_R)

    def change_label_L(self, instance, Label):
        print 'L ', matrix
        counter = matrix[3]
        self.label_L0.text = str(counter-2)
        self.label_L1.text = str(counter-1)
        self.label_L2.text = str(counter)
        self.label_L3.text = str(counter+1)
        self.label_L4.text = str(counter+2)

    def change_label_R(self, instance, BoxLayout):
        print 'R ', matrix
        counter = matrix[4]
        self.label_R0.text = str(counter-2)
        self.label_R1.text = str(counter-1)
        self.label_R2.text = str(counter)
        self.label_R3.text = str(counter+1)
        self.label_R4.text = str(counter+2)

class MyLayout_L(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'scrollup':
                self.calc_plus()
            elif touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                self.calc_minus()
    def calc_plus(self):
        matrix[3] += 1
    def calc_minus(self):
        matrix[3] -= 1

class MyLayout_R(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'scrollup':
                self.calc_plus2()
            elif touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                self.calc_minus2()
    def calc_plus2(self):
        matrix[4] += 1
    def calc_minus2(self):
        matrix[4] -= 1

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Now, the problem is that the code has some strange behavior. The classes `MyLayout_R` and `MyLayout_L` have been created in order to recognize whether the cursor of the mouse is located to the left of right BoxLayout, and make the `on_touch_down` events trigger the `change_label_R` or `change_label_L` functions.

Yet, in the terminal I see that both functions are triggered simultaneously (see the `print 'L ', matrix` and `print 'R ', matrix` lines in the code which are both executed while scrolling).

Also, the labels in the BoxLayouts are changing, but not exactly as planned.

- When I change the location of the cursor, the left BoxLayout label
  will always skip a step (compare the terminal output and the labels).
- Also, when changing the location, the first scrolling will trigger
  the old Boxlayout and the next scrollings will trigger the present
  one.

Since `collide_point` checks if the cursor is located inside the area of the widget at hand, why does scrolling affects both BoxLayouts? I guess that I miss something important here, thus any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, edited to only have one on_touch_down() method for each of your MyLayout classes.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

matrix = [500, 500, 500, 5, 5]

class LoginScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        self.container_L = MyLayout_L(orientation = 'vertical', on_touch_down = self.change_label_L)
        self.container_M = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.container_R = MyLayout_R(orientation = 'vertical', on_touch_down = self.change_label_R)

        self.label_L0 = Label(text = '3', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L1 = Label(text = '4', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L2 = Label(text = '5', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L3 = Label(text = '6', font_size = 30)
        self.label_L4 = Label(text = '7', font_size = 30)

        label_L_list = [self.label_L0, self.label_L1, self.label_L2, self.label_L3, self.label_L4]
        for item in label_L_list:
            self.container_L.add_widget(item)

        self.label_M0 = Label(text = '500', font_size = 30)
        label_M_list = [self.label_M0]
        for item in label_M_list:
            self.container_M.add_widget(item)

        self.label_R0 = Label(text = '3', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R1 = Label(text = '4', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R2 = Label(text = '5', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R3 = Label(text = '6', font_size = 30)
        self.label_R4 = Label(text = '7', font_size = 30)

        label_R_list = [self.label_R0, self.label_R1, self.label_R2, self.label_R3, self.label_R4]
        for item in label_R_list:
            self.container_R.add_widget(item)

        self.add_widget(self.container_L)
        self.add_widget(self.container_M)
        self.add_widget(self.container_R)

    def change_label_L(self, instance, touch):
        if instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'L ', matrix
            counter = matrix[3]
            self.label_L0.text = str(counter-2)
            self.label_L1.text = str(counter-1)
            self.label_L2.text = str(counter)
            self.label_L3.text = str(counter+1)
            self.label_L4.text = str(counter+2)
            if touch.button == 'scrollup':
                instance.calc_plus()
            elif touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                instance.calc_minus()


    def change_label_R(self, instance, touch):
        if instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'R ', matrix
            counter = matrix[4]
            self.label_R0.text = str(counter-2)
            self.label_R1.text = str(counter-1)
            self.label_R2.text = str(counter)
            self.label_R3.text = str(counter+1)
            self.label_R4.text = str(counter+2)
            if touch.button == 'scrollup':
                instance.calc_plus2()
            elif touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                instance.calc_minus2()

class MyLayout_L(BoxLayout):
    def calc_plus(self):
        matrix[3] += 1
    def calc_minus(self):
        matrix[3] -= 1

class MyLayout_R(BoxLayout):
    def calc_plus2(self):
        matrix[4] += 1
    def calc_minus2(self):
        matrix[4] -= 1

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Yet, the problem is still not solved. It seems that there is still a gap between the numbers in terminal and the numbers displayed in the labels. When I change BoxLayout, the first scrolling will trigger the previous BoxLayout. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `collide_point()` is working correctly. The problem is that you have set two methods to handle `on_touch_down` events for each class. The ones that you create in `self.container_L = MyLayout_L(orientation = 'vertical', on_touch_down = self.change_label_L)` and similarly for "R" do not use `collide_point()`, so they execute on every event.

Comment: Abderson Thank you for your responce. Could you possibly suggest a way to overcome this problem?